# Azure Databricks : Mount delta table used in another workspace

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Currently I have an azure databricks instance where I have the following

```
myDF.withColumn("created_on", current_timestamp())\
.writeStream\
.format("delta")\
.trigger(processingTime= triggerDuration)\
.outputMode("append")\
.option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/datalake/_checkpoint_Position")\
.option("path", "/mnt/datalake/DeltaData")\
.partitionBy("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")\
.table("deltadata")
```

This is saving the data into a storage account as blobs.

Now, I'm trying to connect to this table from another azure databricks workspace and my first "move" is the mount to the azure storage account:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = sourceString,
    mountPoint = "/mnt/data",
    extraConfigs = Map(confKey -> sasKey)
```

Note: sourceString, confKey and sasKey are not shown for obvious reasons, in any case the mount works fine.

And then I try to create the table, but I get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE delta_data USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/data/DeltaData/'

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: 
You are trying to create an external table `default`.`delta_data`
from `/mnt/data/DeltaData` using Databricks Delta, but the schema is not specified when the
input path is empty.
```

According to the documentation the schema should be picked up from the existing data correct?
Also, I trying to do this in a different workspace because the idea is to give only read access to people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems my issue was the mount. It did not give any error while creating it but was not working fine. I discovered this after trying:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/data/DeltaData")
```

Which was not showing anything. I unmounted and reviewed all the configs and after that it worked.